# Why is this function not returning and or value getting stuck?

Tags: c++, function, templates, linked-list

I written a function that compares an argument to to the values inside a linked list and returns the number the argument appears in the linked list, but it appears to not be working properly as it appears to be getting stuck when I call the function. Below is some of the code I used primarily the main function and the function where the program gets stuck, additionally here is some sample output [link to output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySdGu.jpg).

```
#include "linkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int num;

linkedListType<int> list1;
cout << "Enter the numbers you wish to store on the list to stop enter -999:";
cin >> num;
while (num != -999)
{
    list1.insert(num);
    cin >> num;
}

list1.print();
cout << "\nEnter the number for whom you wish to know how many times it appears in the list\n";
cin >> num;
cout << "The number of times " << num << " appears in the lis is: " << list1.numberOfTimesItemAppears(num);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

//function in linkedListType


template <class Type>
int linkedListType<Type>::numberOfTimesItemAppears(const Type& searchItem)
{
     int count=0;
     nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
     current = first; //set current to point to the first
     //node in the list

while (current != NULL) //search the list
{
    if (current->info == searchItem)
    {
        current = current->link;
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: You only set `current = current->link;` (move forwards) if you found the item. Move it outside the `if`.

Comment: And when you executed your code in the debugger, what observations have you made about the execution flow in `numberOfItemsItemAppears()` function?

Comment: Thank you so much #Ryan I can't believe I overlooked this mistake. I wonder If all beginner programmers make these types of mistakes as often as I do. I seriously need to learn how to use the debbuger.